# Angularjs Override ng-show ng-hide on :hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a series of "icons" that I show in my template.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in items | orderBy:'-timestamp'">
    <div class="icon">
        <i>1</i>
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following css to show `span` when `.icon` is hovered over and hide `i`.

```
.icon:hover i { display: none; }
.icon:hover span { display: block; }
```

However, I also want to be able to show every single instance of `span` when `$scope.options == true`. So I added the following:

```
<i ng-hide="options">1</i>
<span ng-show="options">2</span>
```

But now, my `:hover` is broken and doesn't end up showing the `span`.

Is there a way to override the `ng-show` so that my css will still `display:block` when it is hovered?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZksTDGNkFShuZt5qzmQ?p=preview)

You can skip the css and let angular handle it using ng-mouseenter/ng-mouseleave.  Then use an `or` to have it show when a second variable goes true.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in items | orderBy:'-timestamp'">
    <div ng-mouseenter="options=true" ng-mouseleave="options=false" class="icon">
        <i ng-hide="options || checkbox">1</i>
        <span ng-show="options || checkbox">2</span>
    </div>

</div>
<input type='checkbox' ng-model="checkbox" ng-click="options=!options">Show
```

Comment: Solid work around. Thanks for this, much better than changing the style to use  `!important`

Comment: Lovely answer @tpie

Answer (score 2):

use the `$scope.options` value to add a class to your `.icon` div, then make a more specific CSS rule to overrride the `:hover` event.

```
<div class="icon" ng-class="{ override: $scope.options == true }">
  <i ng-hide="options">1</i>
  <span ng-show="options">2</span>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.icon.override:hover i { display: block; }
.icon.override:hover span { display: block; }
```